# SQL Server State session database separate

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is a very simple question actually. But need to know more deeply. 
I am trying to store my session to SQL State.. Then i run some command from aspnet_regsql.exe. It creates another database on SQL Server.

My question is: Why it needs to create another database? Is it possible to create it inside our own database(app database)??

Advice please. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't - you can specify a specific data base on the command line : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Ok. How if i run it manually from query editor? Open InstallSqlState.sql and do some modification on it?